# Central limit theorem

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

From the Lindeberg-Levy central limit theorem, if $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $EX_i = \mu$ and  $\mathrm{Var}X_i = \sigma^2 <\infty,$ then as $n\to\infty$ the random variables converge in distribution as follows
$$\frac{X_1+\ldots +X_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}} \to N(0,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}}$$

I have two questions about the results of this theorem.

(1) From here what can be said about the convergence of 
$$\Bigg( \frac{X_1+\ldots +X_n - \mu}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg)^k$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is it as simple as raising $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}}$ to the k-th power?
So as $n\to\infty$,
$$\Bigg( \frac{X_1+\ldots +X_n - \mu}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg)^k \longrightarrow \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}}\Big)^k?$$

(2) What can we say about 
$$E \Bigg( \frac{X_1+\ldots +X_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}}\Bigg)^k$$
as $n\to \infty?$
Does the argument still converge to the normal distribution or a variation of the normal distribution as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: (1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem (2) The expectation is identically 0 (use linearity of expectation).

Comment: " Is it as simple as raising $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}}$ to the $k-$th power " ? Why would it? That's not even a valid distribution.

Comment: BTW, you are missing a $n$ ( $\cdots - n\mu$) in the first fraction.

Comment: Your second question is rather trivial, and suggests that you have not yet grasped what the CLT says. Call $Z= (X_1+ \cdots + X_n - n \mu)/\sqrt{n}$. THen, if you know that $Z$ tends in distribution to a normal of mean 0, then trivially you know that $E(Z) \to 0$. Further, this later result (apart from being contained in the CLT) is much simpler, almost direct.

Comment: @leonbloy I should rewrite my second question because I'm actually interested in knowing $E(Z)^k$ where $Z$ is the same one from your comment.

Comment: @Batman Thank you for the link for (1). For (2), I've rewritten my question because I'm actually interested in knowing $E(X_1+\ldots+X_n−n\mu)/\sqrt{n})^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $$Z= \frac{X_1+ \cdots + X_n - n \mu}{\sqrt{n}}$$ 
and knowing that $Z \to N(0, \sigma^2)$ then we [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) that $E(Z^k)\to \sigma^k (k-1)!!$ if $k$ is even, $0$ otherwise.